# Monitoring SD/TF Card status while interfacing with separate host

Tags: flash, sd, camera

I'm working on project that requires taking several terabytes worth of RAW photos on DSLR controlled by a microcontroller. Initially the plan was to use a small Linux SBC running some kind of control software (gPhoto2 likely) that would trigger image capture and store the photos in a bank of drives. I'd really like to simplify and miniaturize this solution if possible.

The thought now is a bank of SD Cards (maybe eMMC) selectable through some kind of mux tree like this [FSSD06](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FSSD06-D.pdf). Essentially a scaled up version of [this](https://thepihut.com/products/2-in-1-sd-card-dual-system-switcher-for-raspberry-pi). The big uncertainty though comes from knowing when an SD card is full and the controller should switch to the next empty one. I'm looking for some kind of middleman type host controller that sit between the camera's SD interface and the SD card itself that can provide information about the state of the SD while forwarding communication through it. Am I dreaming of something that doesn't exist or does someone have another solution to this problem? I'd really appreciate any input - thanks

Comment: This sounds a lot like RAID.

Comment: It is a RAID configuration, but the few SD card raid controllers that exist only offer SATA interfaces. If there was a multiple SD to SD RAID controller I'd be all over it, but I can't find one.

Comment: Why not just configure the microcontroller to use a NAS instead? Seems like you are trying to design a massive storage system into a small MCU that really isn't designed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've played quite a bit with MCU and sd cards, but at the end of the day, an embedded Linux still the best solution if you don't want to spend countless hours working on filesystem stacks to make it work on MCUs while linux already has all the support you need.

You can have a cheap small form factor system with the following:

Platform: Atheros AR9931 type of chip with OpenWRT or something equivalent. There is plenty of modules board available that has some IO and the ram/flash for about the same price as a high-end MCU.

To control the SD cards:

- Option A is SPI (or specific card protocol) with a multiplexer to access specific cards, you can basically have an unlimited amount of SD cards.
- Option B, easier, use the USB port, with USB hub chip (you can chain several) and card reader chips.